# "chmod / 775 -R" and now our mysql database is down...!

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to repair/restore ubuntu 10.04 after 'sudo chmod / 777'](https://serverfault.com/questions/221447/how-to-repair-restore-ubuntu-10-04-after-sudo-chmod-777)

It looks like there are some related issues to my problem.. One of our team members accidentally ran "chmod / 775 -R" and now we've got some issues with our database..

I'm getting stuff that looks like this : Incorrect information in file: '*.frm'

Any help to get us back on our feet would be awesome

Comment: Hopefully you have a good backup?!  Seriously, because the chmod doesn't differentiate between files and directories so the fact the Mysql isn't running is only the tip of the iceberg.  If anything you need something that can restore the original permissions of your entire filesystem.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend rebuilding the server but you probably have a problem with your `/tmp`, try chmodding it to `777`.

But you will come across various other issues. Take your backups or what you need and rebuild the system from scratch.

Also, take a look at this: [How to repair/restore ubuntu 10.04 after `sudo chmod / 777`](https://serverfault.com/questions/221447/how-to-repair-restore-ubuntu-10-04-after-sudo-chmod-777)