# Upload File /Apache :: Failed to open stream: Permission denied on CentOS

Tags: php, files, upload, permissions

uploading file to server is always giving me this error though I tried all solution on the web for this problem but I'm still getting this error no matter what :

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(/home/safaa/uploads/d.txt): failed to open
>   stream: Permission denied in
>   /var/www/html/Administration/newEmptyPHP.php on line 47
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/php6qK4Df' to
>   '/home/safaa/uploads/d.txt' in
>   /var/www/html/Administration/newEmptyPHP.php on line 47

Here's my HTML code :

```
     <form id="file_to_upload" name="file_to_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="newEmptyPHP.php" method="post" >
            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
            Browse for a root certificate to upload:
            <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
             <input type="submit" value="Upload It Now" onclick="$('#file_to_upload').submit();">
    </form>
```

my PHP code :

```
 $file_name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];

//User can upload only till 100kb file size.
    $file_tmp_name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];
    $upload_path = "/home/safaa/uploads/" . $file_name;
//function for upload file
            if (move_uploaded_file($file_tmp_name, $upload_path)) {
                echo "Successful<BR>";
            }
```

I've tried these following solutions which they are all what I found on the web forums and stackoverflow questions and answers :

1. Change permission of /tmp/ and /uploads/ to 777 and 0777 . "it didn't work"
2. in php.ini , safe mode is off and file_uploads is on
3. SELinux is Disabled :: getenforce gave me Disabled

> ```
>  drwxrwxrwx.   6 nobody  root      4096 Jul 20 13:06 tmp
>
>  drwxrwxrwx   2 nobody safaa  4096 Jul 17 15:17 uploads
> ```

neither of both worked .

Comment: Check [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive) and [here](http://stopdisablingselinux.com/). I hope this is a development machine, and not something somebody's business depends on.

Comment: of course it's a development server ! and if you hit "failed to open stream: Permission denied" on google search , you'll find that all search results would give you what I have written !

Comment: what are the permissions on `/home/safaa`? (`ls -lrtd /home/safaa`)

Comment: it's `drwx------. 8 safaa safaa 4096 Jul 17 15:17 /home/safaa`

Comment: but it's a bad practice , do you suggest an alternative way ?

Comment: Well, you should start re-enabling all the stuff you removed (safemode, SELinux), implement a firewall, make sure user accounts is secure etc. I don't know enough about PHP to verify if a code is proper or not.

Answer (score 1):

Your permissions on the /tmp share is incorrect.

Try the following: `chmod a+rwxt /tmp /var/tmp`

Comment: thanks , changing /home/safaa permission solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You got the error "Failed to open stream: access denied". What to do?

1. Find out the php error code. Place this code at the beginning of your php.

```php
    ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL); ini_set ('display_errors', 1); ini_set ('display_startup_errors', 1);
```

2. The folder must be accessible 777. Check it.
3. The  tag must have the enctype = "multipart / form-data" method = "post" attribute.

```html
    <form enctype = "multipart / form-data" method = "post">
```

4. Fully open and view the $ _FILES array on the server.

```
    print_r ($ _FILES);
```

5. Open and view the $ _FILES array on the client.

```
    file = document.getElementById ("get_avatar"). files [0]; parts = file.name.split ('.');
```

```
   var a = file.size; var b = parts.pop (); var c = file.type; alert (a + b + c);
```

6. Check the rights of the user and user group to the directory.

```sh
    cd / var / www / your_site / user
    ls -l
```

More details: [enter link description here](http://profi.spage.me/php/check-file-input-on-php-and-jquery-why-error)

Comment: Never use chmod 777 for anything.