# vsftpd - libz.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied

Tags: permissions, ftp

> ## /etc/init.d/vsftpd start Starting vsftpd for vsftpd: /usr/sbin/vsftpd: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1:
>
> failed to map segment from shared object: Permission denied
>                                                              [FAILED]

I am afraid that this has something to do with a previous disaster happened. I accidentally changed most of the files permission in this CentOS box to 777.

So I have located this libz.so.1 file which is a link to libz.so.1.2.3 and they are all 777 now.

I don't know what to do with them. Help please?

```
[root@deadwood repo01]# ls --lcontext /lib64/libz.so.1 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 system_u:object_r:lib_t          root root 13 Aug  9 07:55 /lib64/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3 
[root@deadwood repo01]# ls --lcontext /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
-rwxrwxrwx 1 system_u:object_r:lib_t          root root 85544 Jul 17  2012 /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3 
[root@deadwood repo01]# ls --lcontext /lib/libz.so.1 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 system_u:object_r:lib_t          root root 13 Aug  9 07:55 /lib/libz.so.1 -> libz.so.1.2.3 
[root@deadwood repo01]# ls --lcontext /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
-rwxr-xr-x 1 system_u:object_r:lib_t          root root 75088 Jul 17  2012 /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
```

Comment: Te best thing you can do here is rebuild your system it really will be easier than trying to fix it http://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive

Comment: Can you show us the output for `ls --lcontext /path/to/libz.so.1` ?

Comment: yes, here they are.

Comment: Just to be sure, can you try `1) set permissions 755 on file /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3` and `2) Disable SELinux`

Comment: Unbelievable! I didn't want to reboot. So I just change enforcing to permissive. It worked now! You can answer and I'll tick! Tks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should try to disable `SELinux`, or change it from `enforcing` to `permissive`.