# SSH and many other programs are not working after chmod -r 755 /etc

Tags: ssh, debian, chmod

I have a new web-admin and he mistakenly ran `chmod -r 755 /etc` to try and disallow our shell users from reading any other files. As a result, SSH on our server does not work. How can we fix this?

Comment: Do note that your situation is more serious than just `sshd` not running. You'll really want to fix the other permissions as well.  (Just as an example, have a look at `/etc/shadow`)

Comment: You should read this http://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive @HåkanLindqvist is correct. There may be some help in http://serverfault.com/search?q=repair+777 but it's probably best to reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make the ssh server keys only readable by root again:

```
chmod 600 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*_key
```

may do the job

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! If you have a BTC address, I'd be more than glad to send some your way :D